# Why is my nested div pushing down my content?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to put my div,"title", inside my "header" div. The problem is I try to center it between my image and my "social" header but it just overlaps and pushes the divs down. How can I center it between those two to have be able to put text so I can make a title?

```css
   body {
      background : #b3d9ff;
      margin : 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family : Futura;
     }
     #wrapper {
      width: 960px;
      height: auto;
      background: #cce5ff;
      border-left: 5px solid #737373;
      border-right: 5px solid #737373;
      overflow : auto;
      margin : 0 auto;
      padding: 10px;
     }
     #header {
      width:100%;
      height:100px;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
      clear: right;
     }
     #header > img {
      margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
     }
     #social {
      float: right;
      margin: 20px 30px 0px 0px;
     }
     #social ul li {
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      padding-right: 5px;
     }
     #sidebar {
      float: left;
      width: 275px;
      height: 100%;
     }
     #menu {
      float: left;
      height: auto;
      width: 200px;
     }
     #menu ul li {
      list-style : none;
      padding: 0px;
      text-align: center;
     }
     #menu ul li a {
      color: #666666;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
     }
     #menu ul li a:visited{
      color:purple;
     }
     #menu ul li a:hover {
      color:black;
     }
     #content {
      float: left;
      width: 655px;
      height: 100%;
      padding-left: 15px;
      letter-spacing : 1;
      border-left: 3px solid black;
     }
     h1 {
      text-align: center;
      padding : 5px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
     }
     p {
      text-indent: 50px;
      line-height: 25px;
     }
     .top a {
      color : #666666;
      text-decoration: none;
     }
     #readMore {
      text-align: right;
     }
     #readMore a:visited {
      color:purple;
     }
     #footer {
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
      height: 80px;
      color: black;
      border-top: 3px solid black;
     }
     h5 {
      text-align: center;
      color: #666666;
     }
     #title {
      position relative
     }
```

```html
   <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header">
      <div id="title"><h2>Title centered in header</h2></div>
      <a name="top"></a>
        <img src="https://janikvonrotz.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Python-Logo.png" width="232" height="101" alt="Logo" title="python">
      <div id="social">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/GallardoBrayan" target="_blank"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/512/Github-icon.png" width="55" height="55"alt="github" title="github"></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div> <!-- End of social -->
     </div> <!-- End of header -->
     <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="menu">
       <ul>
        <li><h4><a href="index.html">Home</a></h4></li>
        <li><h4><a href="overview">Overview</a></h4></li>
       </ul>
      </div> <!-- End of menu -->
     </div> <!-- End of sidebar -->
     <div id="content">
    
    <a name="overview"><h1>Overview</h1>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
    Sample
    </pre>
    <div class="top"><h4><a href="#top">Back To Top</a></h4></div>
    
    
     </div> <!-- End of content -->
     <div id="footer">
      <h5>2016 &copy Brayan Rafael Gallardo </br><a href="mailto:?subject=Sample">Contact me</a></h5>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- End of wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You made a simple mistake you hardcoded the height of your `header` to `100px;`

Just set this to auto.

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jz9vcbfr/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "float: right" to the title element's style.  You might also want to look in to flexbox, which makes alignments like this pretty trivial, and is simpler to get your head around than floats.  [Here's a great resource to get you started.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

so what did i do  i changed the position of the logo i put it before your title and then i centered it with flexbox

```css
  body {
        background : #b3d9ff;
        margin : 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family : Futura;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: 960px;
        height: auto;
        background: #cce5ff;
        border-left: 5px solid #737373;
        border-right: 5px solid #737373;
        overflow : auto;
        margin : 0 auto;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #header {
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
        clear: right;
        display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
    }
    #header > img {
        margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    #social {
        float: right;
        margin: 20px 30px 0px 0px;
    }
    #social ul li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    #sidebar {
        float: left;
        width: 275px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #menu {
        float: left;
        height: auto;
        width: 200px;
    }
    #menu ul li {
        list-style : none;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #menu ul li a {
        color: #666666;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    #menu ul li a:visited{
        color:purple;
    }
    #menu ul li a:hover {
        color:black;
    }
    #content {
        float: left;
        width: 655px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-left: 15px;
        letter-spacing : 1;
        border-left: 3px solid black;
    }
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        padding : 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    p {
        text-indent: 50px;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    .top a {
        color : #666666;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #readMore {
        text-align: right;
    }
    #readMore a:visited {
        color:purple;
    }
    #footer {
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        color: black;
        border-top: 3px solid black;
    }
    h5 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #666666;
    }
    #title {
        position relative
       
    }
```

```html
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    
     <img src="https://janikvonrotz.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Python-Logo.png" width="232" height="101" alt="Logo" title="python">
        <div id="title">
        <h2>Title centered in header</h2></div>
        <a name="top"></a>
        <div id="social">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/GallardoBrayan" target="_blank"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/512/Github-icon.png" width="55" height="55"alt="github" title="github"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- End of social -->
    </div> <!-- End of header -->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><h4><a href="index.html">Home</a></h4></li>
                <li><h4><a href="overview">Overview</a></h4></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- End of menu -->
    </div> <!-- End of sidebar -->
    <div id="content">

<a name="overview"><h1>Overview</h1>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
Sample
</pre>
<div class="top"><h4><a href="#top">Back To Top</a></h4></div>


    </div> <!-- End of content -->
    <div id="footer">
        <h5>2016 &copy Brayan Rafael Gallardo </br><a href="mailto:?sub
```

Comment: What does flex: direction do? I tried using your solution but it still doesn't display correctly. I'm using sublime text editor and the flex keywords are not color coded like the rest if that matters.

Comment: if they are white that is normal!  what does flex-direction do: so in this case i use ROW  what is mean i want then all in one line and i sad : justify-content:space-between; what makes that the space between the 3 is the same so like that the title is and stays in the middle. flexbox is really good i like to work with it  it makes alot of times work fast and easy

Answer (score 0):

It is the bad practice to place the hardcoded values where not required (such as margins which should vary as per the browser window size) instead use em, vw or % values where ever possible. Use HTML strictly for Structuring don't put height, width etc in the code. Always use CSS for such styling purpose.

Don't set header to 100px as said by @Roman  its is really bad.
Use `position: relative; float:left;` and `display: inline-block;` to achieve desired results for title, social and img inside header.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
      background : #b3d9ff;
      margin : 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family : Futura;
     }
     #wrapper {
      width: 960px;
      height: auto;
      background: #cce5ff;
      border-left: 5px solid #737373;
      border-right: 5px solid #737373;
      overflow : auto;
      margin : 0 auto;
      padding: 10px;
     }
     #header {
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
      clear: right;
     }
     #header > img {
      margin: 1em 0 0 0;
            width: 232px;
            height: 101px;
            position: relative;
            float:left;
     }
     #social {
       position: relative;
      float: right;
            display:inline-block;
      margin: 1em 1.2em 0 0;
     }
     
     #social ul li {
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      padding-right: 5px;
     }
     #sidebar {
      float: left;
      width: 275px;
      height: 100%;
     }
     #menu {
      float: left;
      height: auto;
      width: 200px;
     }
     #menu ul li {
      list-style : none;
      padding: 0px;
      text-align: center;
     }
     #menu ul li a {
      color: #666666;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
     }
     #menu ul li a:visited{
      color:purple;
     }
     #menu ul li a:hover {
      color:black;
     }
     #content {
      float: left;
      width: 655px;
      height: 100%;
      padding-left: 15px;
      letter-spacing : 1;
      border-left: 3px solid black;
     }
     h1 {
      text-align: center;
      padding : 5px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
     }
     p {
      text-indent: 50px;
      line-height: 25px;
     }
     .top a {
      color : #666666;
      text-decoration: none;
     }
     #readMore {
      text-align: right;
     }
     #readMore a:visited {
      color:purple;
     }
     #footer {
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
      height: 80px;
      color: black;
      border-top: 3px solid black;
     }
     h5 {
      text-align: center;
      color: #666666;
     }
     #title {
      position relative;
           float:left;
           margin: 1.1em 0 0 7em;
     }
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header">
        <img src="https://janikvonrotz.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Python-Logo.png"  alt="Logo" title="python">
      <div id="title"><h2>Title centered in header</h2></div>
      <a name="top"></a>
        
      <div id="social">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/GallardoBrayan" target="_blank"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/512/Github-icon.png" width="55" height="55"alt="github" title="github"></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div> <!-- End of social -->
     </div> <!-- End of header -->
     <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="menu">
       <ul>
        <li><h4><a href="index.html">Home</a></h4></li>
        <li><h4><a href="overview">Overview</a></h4></li>
       </ul>
      </div> <!-- End of menu -->
     </div> <!-- End of sidebar -->
     <div id="content">
    
    <a name="overview"><h1>Overview</h1>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
    Sample
    </pre>
    <div class="top"><h4><a href="#top">Back To Top</a></h4></div>
    
    
     </div> <!-- End of content -->
     <div id="footer">
      <h5>2016 &copy Brayan Rafael Gallardo </br><a href="mailto:?subject=Sample">Contact me</a></h5>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- End of wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... when ur trying to keep sth in between sth try keeping the stuff in between the other two stuff... use display:inline-block to keep other elements on the same line... since u want the social image to be on the right side ... use display:inline-block with the #title and float: right with the social image

```
        #wrapper {
        width: 960px;
        height: auto;
        background: #cce5ff;
        border-left: 5px solid #737373;
        border-right: 5px solid #737373;
        overflow : auto;
        margin : 0 auto;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #header {
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
        display:inline-block;

    }
    #header > img {
        float:left;
        margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    #title{ 
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        display:inline-block;
    }

    #social {
        float: right;
        margin: 20px 30px 0px 0px;
    }


<div id="header">
        <div id="title"><h2>Title centered in header</h2></div> 
        <a name="top"></a>
              <img src="your image" width="232" height="101" alt="Logo" title="python">

        <div id="social">
            <a href="https://github.com/GallardoBrayan" target="_blank"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/512/Github-icon.png" width="55" height="55"alt="github" title="github"></a>         
        </div> <!-- End of social -->
    </div>
```